# Azure SQL Database Row Number not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, row-number

I am trying to run ROWNUMBER on an instance of Azure SQL Database. It just does not work.

```
;WITH cteA AS
(
    SELECT 1 as Test1, 2 as Test2, 3 as Test3
    UNION ALL Select 1, 1, 1
    UNION ALL Select 1, 1, 1
    UNION ALL Select 2, 1, 3
    UNION ALL Select 2, 1, 3
)
SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARITION BY a.test1 ORDER BY A.test1) AS RN
FROM 
    cteA A
```

This is the output I get:

```
Test1   |Test2   |Test3   |RN
1       |1       |1       |1
1       |1       |1       |2
1       |2       |3       |3
2       |1       |3       |1
2       |1       |3       |2
```

Not sure why? I am expecting RN to be 1-1-1-2-2

Comment: The `PARTITION BY a.test1` creates "partitions" (or "groups" / "buckets") of rows with the same values - here one group is with all the `test1 = 1` rows, the other one is with `test1 = 2`. Within each group, the rows are consecutively numbered, starting at 1 - that's why you're getting the results you're seeing (and those are **correct** - given what code you've written)

Answer (score 3):

Given your expected results, I think that you actually want:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY A.test1)
```

This gives you an incremental number that increases by 1 everytime `Test1` changes.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b9bf945c88f966cf370c5bc8d7c8f076)**:

```
Test1 | Test2 | Test3 | RN
----: | ----: | ----: | :-
    1 |     1 |     1 | 1               
    1 |     1 |     1 | 1               
    1 |     2 |     3 | 1               
    2 |     1 |     3 | 2               
    2 |     1 |     3 | 2
```